# Tomcat exception: java.lang.NullPointerException utils.ManageIP.validIp (ManageIP.java:113)

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

Our Tomcat server is generating 500 errors and spitting out the following stack trace, but Googling for the root cause (i.e., utils.ManageIP.validIp) doesn't yield anything.

Why would `utils.ManageIP.validIp` be null?

Here's the code causing the lovely exception:

```
String IP = request.getRemoteAddr();
if (!utils.ManageIP.validIp(IP)) {
   // Do stuff
}
```

Confused. Any ideas?

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:541)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:435)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:694)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:665)
    org.apache.jsp.admin_jsp._jspService(admin_jsp.java:87)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:393)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    utils.ManageIP.validIp(ManageIP.java:113)
    org.apache.jsp.jsp.mainMenu_jsp._jspService(mainMenu_jsp.java:88)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:393)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:694)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:665)
    org.apache.jsp.admin_jsp._jspService(admin_jsp.java:87)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:393)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/6.0.14 logs.
```

Comment: utils.ManageIP? what is it? your own library?

Comment: @Ursache ahhh no wonder Googling yielded nothing. :) Legacy code from the original dev. Thanks!

Comment: @Ursache please post as an answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

utils.ManageIP? what is it? your own library?

edit: the comments proved that, it is a legacy dev code.